# hexToNumberString not require in new web3 versions?

Tags: web3js

I have such code before

```
let profit = await contract.methods.calculateFundProfit().call()
   profit = web3.utils.hexToNumberString(profit._hex)
```

but after update web3 version, do I need do only this?

```
let profit = await contract.methods.calculateFundProfit().call()
```

Comment: What was your web3 version before and what is it now?

Comment: There is generally a lot of confusion about web3 versions. First of all, Truffle 4.x relies on Web3 0.x, and Truffle 5.x relies on Web3 1.x. Between these two versions of Web3, there are API differences, which means that your code breaks when you move from one version to the other. Second - even worse - Web3 1.x has been published as a Beta version up until 55, and then finally as a Release version 1.2.x, which relies on... Beta 37...

Comment: So if you've updated to 1.2.x, then it is rellay a question of "where you came from", for example - was it 0.20.6 or 1.0.0-34 or 1.0.0-55? Each case would yield a different set of problems in your code.